# Appending elements to a vector results in subsequent failed sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a 2 vectors: an Element vector and a Count vector. When sorting the Element vector, I need to sort the count vector corresponding to the Element vector values. I need to append the Element vector to a Global vector (Proc) with its corresponding Proc_count vector, which gradually increases in size, and repeats the above sorting process.

However the second sorting step fails after appending elements to the end of the Proc and Proc_count vector. I am aware that re-sizing a vector invalidates the iterators, however even after using std::reserve, I am noticing the same result.

```
typedef uint64_t data_t;

struct MyComparator
{
   const std::vector<data_t> & value_vector;
   MyComparator(const std::vector<data_t> & val_vec):
          value_vector(val_vec) {}

   bool operator()(int i1, int i2)
  {
    return value_vector[i1] < value_vector[i2];
  }
};

void SortAndAggregate(std::vector<data_t>& arr, std::vector<int>& count, std::vector<int>& add)
{

 sort(count.begin(), count.end(), MyComparator(arr));
 sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    printf("Sorted arr: \n");
    for (std::vector<data_t>::iterator it = arr.begin() ; it != arr.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    printf("Sorted count: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = count.begin() ; it != count.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

 int aggr=0;
 for(int i = 0; i < (int)(arr.size()); i++)
    {
      aggr = count[i];
      if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
          do {
                aggr += count[i+1];
                i++;
             } while(i<(int)arr.size() && (arr[i] == arr[i+1]));
       }
       add.push_back(aggr);
    }

 arr.erase( unique( arr.begin(), arr.end() ), arr.end() );
 assert(arr.size() == add.size());

    printf("Sorted add: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = add.begin() ; it != add.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N=20;
    srand(time(0));

    data_t mydata[] = {14,32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33, 9};
    int mycnt[]     = {1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10};
    std::vector<data_t> dummy_data (mydata, mydata+10);
    std::vector<int> dummy_cnt (mycnt, mycnt+10);

    std::vector<data_t> arr1;
    std::vector<int> cnt;
    std::vector<int> arr3;
    std::vector<data_t> proc_buf;
    std::vector<int> proc_buf_cnt;

    proc_buf.reserve(20);
    proc_buf_cnt.reserve(20);

    proc_buf.insert(proc_buf.end(), dummy_data.begin(), dummy_data.end());
    proc_buf_cnt.insert(proc_buf_cnt.end(), dummy_cnt.begin(), dummy_cnt.end());

    SortAndAggregate (proc_buf, proc_buf_cnt, arr3);
    proc_buf_cnt = arr3;
    arr3.clear();

    printf("Proc buffer before: \n");
    for (std::vector<data_t>::iterator it = proc_buf.begin() ; it != proc_buf.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    printf("Proc Count buffer before: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = proc_buf_cnt.begin() ; it != proc_buf_cnt.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
         arr1.push_back(rand() % 10);
         cnt.push_back(i);
    }

    printf("Original array: \n");
    for (int it = 0 ; it < (int)arr1.size(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << arr1[it];
    std::cout << '\n';

    printf("Original counts: \n");
    for (int it = 0; it < (int)cnt.size(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << cnt[it];
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    SortAndAggregate (arr1, cnt, arr3);

    proc_buf.insert(proc_buf.end(), arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
    proc_buf_cnt.insert(proc_buf_cnt.end(), arr3.begin(), arr3.end());
    arr3.clear();

    printf("Proc buffer before: size: %d \n", (int)proc_buf.size());
    for (std::vector<data_t>::iterator it = proc_buf.begin() ; it != proc_buf.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    printf("Proc Count buffer before: size: %d \n", (int)proc_buf_cnt.size());
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = proc_buf_cnt.begin() ; it != proc_buf_cnt.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    SortAndAggregate (proc_buf, proc_buf_cnt, arr3);
    proc_buf_cnt = arr3;

    assert(proc_buf.size() == proc_buf_cnt.size());

    arr1.clear();
    cnt.clear();
    arr3.clear();
    proc_buf.clear();
    proc_buf_cnt.clear();

    return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
   Proc buffer before: 
   9 12 14 26 32 33 45 53 71 80
   Proc Count buffer before: 
   10 9 3 5 1 8 4 7 2 6

   Original Element array: 
   4 6 6 1 7 1 0 7 3 7 8 7 5 0 9 5 6 5 1 3
   original Element counts: 
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

   Sorted arr: 
   0 0 1 1 1 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 9
   Sorted count: 
   6 13 3 18 5 19 8 0 17 15 12 1 16 2 11 9 7 4 10 14 // CORRECT sorted order
   Sorted aggregate: 
   19 26 27 0 44 19 31 10 14

   Appended Proc buffer (size: 19) 
   9 12 14 26 32 33 45 53 71 80 0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   Appended Proc Count buffer (size: 19) 
   10 9 3 5 1 8 4 7 2 6 19 26 27 0 44 19 31 10 14

   Sorted arr: 
   0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 12 14 26 32 33 45 53 71 80
   Sorted count:  
   10 10 19 19 14 31 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 26 27 44 // INCORRECT sorted order ...!!!!
   Sorted aggregate: 
   10 10 19 19 14 31 0 1 5 4 5 6 7 8 9 26 27 44
```

Any clues as to why the second sort is failing? Am I missing something?

Comment: *Am I missing something* --  Yes -- Using your debugger to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I am fairly new to c++, therefore printing the results after every operation, is my way of debugging the problem.

Comment: Well, now is a good time to learn to use the debugger.

Comment: Given the answers, you have multiple issues with your `SortAndAggregate` function.  The output you're showing is basically invalid due to the errors that have been pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer alluded to, you have an out-of-bounds access error.

In addition, you are lucky your program even got as far as it had, since you have an out-of-bounds access on the very first call of `SortAndAggreate`, thus the output you're showing in your question is basically useless since undefined behavior is being invoked.

In your `MyComparator` functor, you're doing this:

```
bool operator()(int i1, int i2)
{
    return value_vector[i1] < value_vector[i2];
}
```

The `value_vector` is a vector that has size==10.  However, the values of `i1` and `i2` eventually become `9`, and `10`, thus you will be accessing an element that's out of bounds.

The problem's genesis is here in `main`:

```
int mycnt[] = {1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10};
```

You use these values as indices when you populate `prof_buf_cnt`, and you're using `prof_buf_cnt` as the indices within the `std::sort` functor `MyComparator`.

The solution, at least here, is to use 0-based indices.

```
int mycnt[] = { 0, 1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

---

Note: If you replaced that line in your `MyComparator` functor with the following:

```
    return value_vector.at(i1) < value_vector.at(i2);
```

you would have seen the issue right away, as an `std::out_of_range` exception would have been thrown.  This would have guaranteed that your program would have stopped with an error, instead of going on and giving the impression that it was working properly (with the only problem being the output being wrong).

---

For an example of how unpredictable undefined behavior can be, see the two links below:

[See this example of your code using `at()`](http://ideone.com/4e9mRc)

[See this example of your code using `[ ]`](http://ideone.com/dMgODq)

Note that the second link above shows your code "working", even though it shouldn't have gone as far as it did, while the first link properly diagnosis the issue by throwing an exception.

Comment: `proc_buf_cnt.insert(proc_buf_cnt.end(), arr3.begin(), arr3.end());` seems in error.  arr3's values (agggegated sums) are not indexes,

Comment: Those values are being used in the functor as indices.  Whether their original purpose was to use them as indices is another story.  That is for the OP to figure out as there are multiple things wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

`i` will be at most `.size()-1` here:

```
 int aggr=0;
 for(int i = 0; i < (int)(arr.size()); i++)
    {
      aggr = count[i];
      if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
```

but you then index the array with `i+1`, which is beyond the last element of `arr`.

Comment: I understand that is a potential bug. But that is not whats causing the problem stated above. The sorting is separate from the aggregate portion. It is the sort operation that is failing.

Comment: @Hello_PG *I understand that is a potential bug...* -- It isn't a potential bug, it is a bug.